# psql variable substitution for postgres script with functions

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a Postgres script that I have that I intend to run against multiple databases. The sample SQL has functions and tables like

```
CREATE FUNCTION point() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
NEW.the_geom:=ST_SetSRID(geom, :CRS) ;
RETURN NEW;
END
$$;

CREATE TABLE admin (
gid integer NOT NULL,
geom geometry(Polygon,:CRS)    
);
```

I have put a variable inside so that I can substitute it on runtime as
 `psql -d db -p 5432 -U username -h localhost -f test.sql --variable=CRS=3857`

Why does the variable only get properly substituted in table definitions and not function definition

Comment: maybe because plpgsql has ':' operator and sql does not?..

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION

> Therefore, a construction such as ':foo' doesn't work to produce a
>   quoted literal from a variable's value (and it would be unsafe if it
>   did work, since it wouldn't correctly handle quotes embedded in the
>   value).

a function definition is put between quotes - in your case `$$` instead of `'`, so it fails. You can change `ST_SetSRID(geom, :CRS)` to `ST_SetSRID(geom, $$:CRS)` to see it start being handled again (of course ruining the function body)

As a workaround you can try using bash variable instead:

```
vao@vao-VirtualBox:~$ export CRS=33
vao@vao-VirtualBox:~$ psql t << EOF
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION point() RETURNS trigger
> LANGUAGE plpgsql
> AS \$\$
> BEGIN
> NEW.the_geom:=ST_SetSRID(geom, $CRS) ;
> RETURN NEW;
> END
> \$\$;
> \sf point()
> EOF
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.point()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
NEW.the_geom:=ST_SetSRID(geom, 33) ;
RETURN NEW;
END
$function$
```

Of course it can be scripted to a file that you can call as bash with argument

Answer (score 0):

Shell substitution, as Vao Tsun suggests, might work fine for small *psql* scripts, but it's still not a general solution. For instance, shells are not aware of *psql* and pgSQL syntaxes and may substitute sub-strings that are not meant to be substituted in the *psql* script:

```sql
-- If CA and AU are undefined environment variable (likely),
-- the following SQL, after shell substitution, will result in:
-- ... VALUES ('Australian Dollar', ''), (Canadian Dollar, '');
INSERT (name, symbol) INTO currencies VALUES 
    ('Australian Dollar', '$AU'),
    ('Canadian Dollar', '$CA');
```

This will become unmanageable with large scripts without additional measures. A better approach is to use string concatenation. Something like this would be ideal:

```
-- This won't work; syntax error
CREATE FUNCTION point() RETURNS trigger 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.the_geom := ST_SetSRID(geom, $$ || :'CRS' || $$);
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
```

Unfortunately, pgSQL syntax expects literal strings as function bodies, not arbitrary string expressions. Fortunately, however, PostgreSQL implements **as part of its SQL syntax** implicit concatenation between single-quoted strings separated by only whitespaces and at least one line break:

```
-- This gets parsed as "SELECT 'mystring';"
SELECT 'my'
   'string';
```

The catch though is that it only works with single-quoted strings, not dollar-quoted strings. The following will work fine, but it's an eye-sore:

```
-- This will work, but it's ugly
CREATE FUNCTION point() RETURNS trigger 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
-- Mind the trailing space below
'BEGIN '
    'NEW.the_geom := ST_SetSRID(geom, $$'
        :'CRS'
    '$$);'
    'RETURN NEW;'
'END';
```

This is perhaps a more eye-pleasing variant:

```
-- This will work
-- (assign appropriate ownership and permissions if CRS contains sentitive data)
CREATE FUNCTION _get_crs() RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql AS 'SELECT $$'
:'crs'
'$$';

CREATE FUNCTION point() RETURNS trigger 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.the_geom := ST_SetSRID(geom, _get_crs());
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
```

And here's another variant:

```sql
-- This will also work
-- (may expose sensitive data in the catalog)
SET "app.crs" = :'crs';

CREATE FUNCTION point() RETURNS trigger 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.the_geom := ST_SetSRID(geom, current_setting('app.crs'));
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

The function body is a sting literal. `psql` has hardly any string modification functionality. However, PostgreSQL has plenty of it. With `psql` variables and `\gset` (since PostgreSQL 9.3) you can utilize this to first build your command and then execute it:

```
--for demo purpose set CRS directly. The OP did pass it from outside to psql
\set CRS 1234
--here we wrap the whole CREATE FUNCTION call in a literal separated by $_$
--this improves the readabilty and covers the inner $$. The result will be
--stored in psql variable func. This is workaround for a multi-line \set 
SELECT $_$
CREATE FUNCTION point() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
NEW.the_geom:=ST_SetSRID(geom, :CRS) ;
RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
$_$ AS func \gset
--replace the substring ':CRS' with content of variable CRS 
--and store the result in func again 
SELECT replace(:'func', ':CRS', :'CRS') AS func \gset
--we can now have a look to the resulting DDL
\echo :func
--and we can execute it:
:func
--clean up psql variables
\unset func
\unset CRS
```

with the help of `\gexec` (since PostgreSQL 9.6) we can also combine the last two steps:

```
--replace the substring ':CRS' with content of variable CRS 
--and execute the result
SELECT replace(:'func', ':CRS', :'CRS') \gexec
```

or even do all in one command:

```
SELECT replace($_$
CREATE FUNCTION point() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
NEW.the_geom:=ST_SetSRID(geom, :CRS) ;
RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
$_$, ':CRS', :'CRS') \gexec
```